# How to enter commands/(SSH password) within the output of a command when using system() in C++?

Tags: c++, ssh, cmd, system

My objective is to connect to an ssh server and enter commands automatically using c++ and system. When running:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   

string user = "user";
string forwarded = "0.tcp.ngrok.io";
string port = "00000";
string command = "ssh "+user+ "@" +forwarded+ " -p "+port; 

system(command.c_str());//connects to ssh server
system("password");//Would like to enter pass within the output of ssh

}
```

It only enter first command and only after exiting the ssh it enters the password (as a command).

Is it possible to add the password within the ssh command (maybe with popen) ?
After that, will it be able to enter commands into the ssh server?

Comment: for security reasons, well implemented apps do not read passwords from stdin. instead they read passwords directly from the tty (usually `/dev/tty`). see tools like [tag:expect] / [tag:pexpect] for how you can manipulate ttys.

Comment: Each `system` call starts a new process. You can't communicate with that process.

Comment: I'd use a key rather than a password for automated SSH logins

Comment: The truth is that `system` is simple to use, but is really feature poor. What you want is certainly possible (even if probably not in a portable way), but not using `system`.

Comment: You could use a library like `libssh`: https://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not.

But perhaps you can use std::cin and std::cout for that, which I would NOT recommend.

I assume you are looking for a library similar to `paramiko` which is, however, in python.